# Better written if statement

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to write an evaluation **if** that runs a piece of code when;

- users has never sent out invites

**OR**

- when the user has sent out invites but a tleast 30 days ago.

I have tried something like this but its not working;

```
<% if !current_user.invites.any? || (Date.today - current_user.invites.last.created_at.to_date) >= 30.days %> 

#some code is run here

<%  end %>
```

What is the best way to go about it?

Comment: did you verify the generated SQL?

Comment: Define "not working". Which part doesn't work? How have you reduced the scope of the problem so you know what's actually failing?

Comment: You could create a method in your `user` model - something like `has_sent_invite_in_last_month?` then it'd be `!current_user.has_sent_invite_in_last_month?` (which would actually also cover the case where he's never sent out an invite if you think about it)

Comment: Try wrapping it up in the brackets.like `<% if ((!current_user.invites.any?) || (Date.today - current_user.invites.last.created_at.to_date) >= 30.days) %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if there are any invitations for that user created in the last 30 days:

```
unless current_user.invites.where("created_at >= ?", 30.days.ago).exists? 
  # ...
end
```

The query should probably be a method in your `User` model.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def has_sent_invite_in_last_month?
    invites.any? && invites.last.created_at > 1.month.ago
  end

end
```

Then:

```
 <% unless current_user.has_sent_invite_in_last_month? %>
   <% #do stuff %>
 <% end %>
```

If a user hasn't sent an invite ever, well then they haven't sent one in the last month, so this wording covers both scenarios.

Comment: Great Idea but `undefined method `count=' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation`

Comment: @user2963716 made it even prettier using your code. Should work nicely :)